# Odoo - Calculation field Import

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

I use Odoo 10 and  have a custom field called sq_cost. When I type in sq_cost it updates standard_price. This works great with the following code

```
@api.onchange('sq_cost')
def _onchange_sq_cost(self):

self.standard_price = (self.sqyards_per_box) * (self.sq_cost)
```

My issue is I have to import a csv and one of the fields to import is sq_cost. The Calculation does not run when I import into sq_cost. If I type it works fine.

Comment: Onchange methods are not triggered via imports. You can create a server action that calls your `onchange` method. You would still need to select the records from the list view, then use the "Action > Your Action".

Comment: Have a look at the base_automation module.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, `@api.onchange()` works on view level for example,

```
=> Edit a record in form view
=> You change value on a `@api.onchange()` field, `sq_cost` in this case
=> `@api.onchange` function is fired, some other field value is changed `standard_price` in this case
**But nothing is changed on the database yet, cause you are still on edit mode**
=> Changes are stored in database only if you press save button.
```

But in case of import from CSV, nothing is changed on view level, values are changed in directly database so none of this process is executed.

Solution:

instead of using `onchange` functionality on view level, you can use `compute function` on your `standard_price` field with `@api.depends('sq_cost')`. This works with in database level, so values will be calculated whenever you import `sq_cost`
value. Somthings to keep in mind:

```
** compute field is by default not stored, set `store=True`
** compute field is by default readonly, set `inverse='inverse_function'` to make this field editable
```